# Get First element in array as array with corresponding key

Tags: php, arrays

Get First element in array  as array with corresponding key

For example,

An

```
Array
(
    [Actor] => 1
    [Producer] => 1
    [Director] => 2
)
```

I want to  get first element with its  corresponding key

```
Array
(
    [Actor] => 1
)
```

How can it be done without looping using some array functions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_slice($arr,0,1)`](http://php.net/array-slice), [`array_splice($arr,0,1);`](http://php.net/array-splice), or [`list($key,$value)=each($arr)`](http://php.net/each) may interest you to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use `list()` and `each()` to get the first element:

```
list($key, $val) = each($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$array = ('actor' => 1, 'producer' => 1, 'director' => 2);
$firstKey = key($array);
$newArray = array();
$newArray[$firstKey] = $array[$firstKey];
var_dump($newArray);
```